# build and release package in sharepoint

Tags: visual-studio, sharepoint, build, visual-sourcesafe, package

I am new to config / build and release management.
We are using VSS for our config management tool and also we are using SharePoint in our project. In VSS we have lot of files like .cs, .snk, .dll, .pdb, .css, .js, .xml etc.
We want to make a build/release as a package for testing that should be an internal delivery. I don't have any idea how to create a build/release package. Can any body give me any suggestion/information how to do this? 
One more thing: due to some internal reasons we can not use any free ware or any other software. Is it possible to do this with visual studio?

Comment: First thing I would do...is replace VSS....

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Mitch, not possible with VSS only. But...if you don´t wan´t to use TFS (Team Foundation Server) which is the preferred option I would recommend looking at [Cruise Control](http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/index.html) for doing your builds.

The other option is to use some sort of custom MSBuild project to package your stuff together, use [WSP Builder](http://www.codeplex.com/wspbuilder) to make that process a bit better. The best way to automate this is still to use TFS or Cruise Control to build your custom MS build project.